# How can I select the value of the nth row in a column in Powerbi?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am fairly new to PowerBi,

I am trying to select the top 3 values from a table but only use specific column values. My instinct is to create a measure for each row. Here is a sample table of the data.

[image: table]

I've tried this but don't know enough of DAX to know how to go any further. I am able to select the top 1 value, but if I change N to 3 it doesnt work. Even if I can choose the second value instead of just the first one would help. Some sort of row index or number in an array fashion.

row[1][name]

```
LowestSpenders = 
    "The lowest spenders for the day are " 
    & 
    CALCULATE(
        VALUES(Top3Low[Name]), 
        TOPN(1, Top3Low, Top3Low[Spent], DESC)
    )
```

I have also tried this

```
LowestSpenders = 
    "The lowest spenders for the day are " 
    & 
    CONCATENATEX(
       Top3Lost,
       VALUES(Top3Lost[ClientName]), 
       ",", 
       Top3Lost[LastYear], 
       DESC
   )
```

I want to select the names of the people based on their positions in the table and include them in a dynamic text measure.

Something like this.

"The lowest spenders for the day are: Bob, John and Mark"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this? Rank all the names and then pick out whatever ranks you want.

```
LowestSpenders =
VAR Summary =
    SUMMARIZE (
        Top3Low,
        Top3Low[Name],
        "Rank", RANK.EQ ( Top3Low[Spent], Top3Low[Spent], 1 )
    )
RETURN
    CONCATENATEX (
        FILTER ( Summary, [Rank] IN { 1, 2, 3 } ),
        [Name],
        ", "
    )
```

Instead of `[Rank] IN { 1, 2, 3 }`, you can substitute whatever criterion you want, for example, `[Rank] = 2` or `[Rank] > 2 && [Rank] < 5`.

Answer (score 1):

You're nearly there.

Use `TOPN` to identify the lowest n spenders, and use `CONCATENATEX` to iterate over this table and concatenate the names:

```
LowestSpenders = 
    CONCATENATEX ( 
        TOPN ( 
            3,
            MyTable,
            MyTable[Spent],
            ASC
        ),
        MyTable[Name],
        ", "
    )
```

Comment: I agree that this helped me solve the specific problem but how would I select only the second value if I needed to?

Comment: This article explains it well: https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/displaying-nth-element-in-dax/